# Dimmer - 120V in, 70V out, normal?

Tags: electrical, wiring, dimmer-switch

I’m redoing a room in my house and I’m replacing a normal switch with a dimmer. I read 120V from hot to ground from the source, and 70V out from the dimmer (Leviton, LED/incandescent compatible). The wiring is pretty straightforward: it’s 2 14/2 wires, whites are connected together with a nut and black from source in the black screw and black that goes to the light on red screw.

Is the 70V after the dimmer normal or it’s faulty? I didn’t connect anything to it yet, I’ve read the reading directly at the end of the wire (about 6 feet).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will never get 100% out of a dimmer, but 70 sounds low. Do you have a trueRMS multimeter or a cheapo unit? A non-RMS one could be mis-sampling the AC voltage given the irregular shape of the resulting AC waveform, which can give an off reading.

I would also check again with a load (bulb) in-place. You might not have enough current to get the triac (the component that "dims" AC) to latch (holding current, often >10ma, aka 1.2 watts in USA) early enough in the sine wave. Adding a load will enable everything to work as designed, which could (should?) fix the issue.

Comment: I will try tonight and report back, thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with your opening statement. Some dimmers have deliberate full output positions (which presumably bypass the dimming mechanism).

Comment: @isherwood, I don't think that's true that dimmers will bypass the dimming mechanism when set to full power.  At least none of the cheap ones, since adding that feature would add a fair amount of cost, and most people wouldn't notice any benefit.

Comment: @NateS. The better ones do.  It's typically past a *detent* that can be fairly stiff, so people don't even realize it's there; when they hit the detent they assume they are at the end of travel and push no further.  There is often a similar detent at the bottom of range, for hard "off".

Comment: FWIW, and I'm not disputing claims, but I've not seen a fully-on capable dimmer. I've used GE, woods, lutron, P+S (legrand), leviton, and many of unknown origin. I would be most welcome to more info about common dimmer that can do that.

Comment: One Lutron we have running four 100 W equivalent LEDs reads 50 V with the slider on bottom and 114 V with slider on top. There is an adjustment lever under the bezel to vary the low level. Measurement with Fluke 115 trms. The lamps are on. I measured voltage through an Isobar plugged into a receptacle in the base of one of the lamps.

Answer (score 2):

If the dimmer in is a dimmed down position, then 70 Volts would be appropriate.  Why are you turning on the power before totally finishing the job? People get hurt with loose hot wires.

Comment: Dimmer is at 100%. I tried at min, still reads 70V. I turned on power to verify voltage only, it’s currently off in the main panel.

Comment: @SimonArsenault  Hook it up per the instructions and see what happens.

Comment: @SimonArsenault follow JACK's recommendation. The only time you should be measuring current is if it's _not_ working as expected. Stopping in the process of wiring _each_ fixture to turn the power on, measure voltage, and turn it back off is _very_ time consuming. I know because when I first started doing wiring on my house, I'd flip the breaker on after wiring up each fixture, just to ensure the breaker didn't trip. After a few, I realized I _did_ know what I was doing and quit bothering with that time consuming and unnecessary step.